# Move array in array of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
[['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i'],['j','k','l']]
```

Now I want to move the last array `['j','k','l']` after array `['a','b','c']` and before array `['d','e','f']`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array.insert(1, array.delete_at(3))
```

This should do it.

Comment: The array has only 4 elements, so this will insert `nil` at index 2.

Comment: You probably ment `array.insert(1, array.delete_at(3))`.

Comment: Huups sorry thank you guys for pointing out! @Wikiti

Comment: `array.delete_at(3)` -> `array.pop` better, I think

Comment: @AlexGolubenko Yes that's a possibility if it is the last item, but i think the generall principle is enough here, depending on use case it could also be shift, find, where etc ...